# Minimization of objective function 300000 xy

Tags: mathematical-optimization

How could I minimize the following in Mathematic?

```
300000 xy
```

under the constraints

```
x >= 0.05 && y > 0 && x - 2 y < 0 && 0.2/xy + 0.27/xy^2 <= 250 && 
  0.2/xy^3 + 0.27/xy^4 <= Pi^2*10^5/216
```

Comment: Try `NMinimize` (please provide Mathematica code!)

Comment: NMinimize[{300000 xy, 
  x >= 0.05 && y > 0 && x - 2 y < 0 && 0.2/xy + 0.27/xy^2 <= 250 && 
   0.2/xy^3 + 0.27/xy^4 <= Pi^2*10^5/216}, {x, y}]

Comment: NMinimize::bcons: The following constraints are not valid: {x>=0.05,y>0,x-2 y<0,0.27/xy^2+0.2/xy<=250,0.27/xy^4+0.2/xy^3<=(12500 \[Pi]^2)/27}. Constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or domain specifications involving the variables. >>

Comment: Check your coding. There should be a blanc between `x and y`?

Comment: Ulrich Neumann Look at the error. what shall i do?

Comment: If you take U@UlrichNeumann's advice, (and be careful about the ambiguity inherent in `0.2/ x y`, i.e. `0.2/ x y != 0.2/(x y)`), then your code will run fine.

Answer (score 3):

You should check the expressions like  `0.2/xy`(**missing space**) ! Does it mean 
`.2/(x y)` or `(.2/x) y)` ?

Assuming the functional (blanc between x,y) you'll get

```
NMinimize[{300000 x y, x >= 0.05 && y > 0 && x - 2 y < 0 && 0.2/x y + 0.27/x y^2 <= 250 && 0.2/x y^3 + 0.27/x y^4 <= Pi^2*10^5/216}, {x, y}]
(*{375., {x -> 0.05, y -> 0.025}}*)
```

this minimum.